# Как в Linux организовано взаимодействие программ с помощью перетаскивания?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, gui, com

В Windows данные действия организованы с помощью COM, OLE, ActiveX и т.д. Недавно обнаружил, что в Ubuntu также можно перетаскивать из окна в окно разные вещи. Как собственно это работает? И как можно сделать самому такое окно, которое может принимать (отдавать) объекты из других окон (в другие окна)?

Comment: к программе linux «перетаскивания» точно не имеют ни малейшего отношения. начните с чтения об [xdnd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection#XDND).

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183517/136975 - не оно же?